# usage of functions with RPN form

Tags: c++, postfix-notation

I'm trying to convert mathematical expressions to RPN and then perform symbolic differentiation on them however I'm stuck with some functions like sin() cos() tan()... ln() sqrt() etc. My expression parser only works for more simple cases, like one from the RPN wiki:

```
3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3
```

produces the following:

```
342*15-23^^/+
```

However when it comes to a more complex formula, like:

```
sin(2*x^2+6)-(cos(x)/(1-x))
```

I can't really create the RPN by hand either. My currently working minimalist solution is again implemented according ot the algorithm defined on the Wiki of Shunting-Yard algorithm.

```
std::string ParseExpression(const std::string &expr) {
    std::string ops = "-+/*^";

    std::stringstream output;
    std::stack<int> stack;

    typedef std::string::const_iterator StringIterator;
    for (StringIterator TOKEN = expr.cbegin(), END = expr.cend(); TOKEN != END; ++TOKEN) {
        const char c = *TOKEN;
        size_t idx = ops.find(c);
        if (idx != std::string::npos) {
            if (stack.empty()) {
                stack.push(idx);
            }
            else {
                while (!stack.empty()) {
                    int prec2 = stack.top() / 2;
                    int prec1 = idx / 2;

                    if (prec2 > prec1 || (prec2 == prec1 && c != '^')) {
                        output << ops[stack.top()];
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                stack.push(idx);
            }
        } else if (c == '(') {
            stack.push(-2);
        } else if (c == ')') {
            while (stack.top() != -2) {
                char op = stack.top();

                stack.pop();

                output << ops[op];
            }

            stack.pop();
        } else {
            output << c;
        }
    }

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        output << ops[stack.top()];
        stack.pop();
    }

    return output.str();
}
```

How can I actually include trigonometric and other functions in the RPN formula and process them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPN works the same for functions (including trigonometrics) as it does for operators.  For trigonometrics, there is only a single argument (unlike operators, which generally have two).

Your example

```
sin(2*x^2+6)-(cos(x)/(1-x))
```

would become something like

```
2x2^*6+_sin_x_cos_1x-/-
```

I put before-and-after underscores around sin and cos functions for clarity.

Taken a little more abstractly, if you think of operators as two-argument functions and trigonometrics as one-argument functions, it may make a little more sense - the function always comes after its arguments and evaluates the preceding args in stack-popping order (last in, first out).  Changing the operators to functions (and appending "b" for binary, "u" for unary) would give us what's below.  RPN says that for anything with a "b" (two arguments), the preceding two args are evaluated in the function.  For functions ending in "u" (one argument), the preceding argument is evaluated.

```
2x2_powb__multb_6_plusb__sinu_x_cosu_1x_minusb__divb__minusb_
```